# Swing ProgressMonitor not working

Tags: java, swing, progressmonitor

I am trying to learn `ProgressMonitor` in Java Swing. 
I created this simple test code -

```
public class ProgressMonitorTest extends JFrame 
{
private JPanel contentPane;
private ProgressMonitor progressMonitor;
private JButton button;
private static ProgressMonitorTest frame;
private static boolean isFrameReady;

public JButton getButton()
{
    return button;
}

public ProgressMonitor getProgressMonitor()
{
    return progressMonitor;
}

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                frame = new ProgressMonitorTest();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                isFrameReady = true;
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    while(!isFrameReady)
    {
        //
    }

    frame.getButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {   
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            try
            {
                for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
                {
                    final int percent = i;
                    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() 
                    {   
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            frame.getProgressMonitor().setProgress(percent * 10);
                            frame.getProgressMonitor().setNote("Completed " + percent*10 + "%.");
                        }
                    });
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ee)
                    {
                        //
                    }                           
                }
            }
            catch(Exception es)
            {
                //
            }
        }           
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public ProgressMonitorTest() 
{
    isFrameReady = false;

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    setTitle("Progress Monitor");

    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    progressMonitor = new ProgressMonitor(frame, "Update in progress...", "", 0, 10);
    button = new JButton("Click Here");
    contentPane.add(button);

    setContentPane(contentPane);
}
```

}

A few questions regarding this-

1. If I remove the `isFrameReady` check, the program says a `NullPointerException` at the line where I assign the button's action listener.
2. If I keep the above check, then clicking on the button does nothing.
3. Keeping the above check and then debugging this, I let it wait for some time before it gets to the line where the action listener. In this case, it works but immediately quits saying it can't call `invokeAndWait` from the event handling thread.

What am I missing in all this ? Can someone explain how to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I remove the isFrameReady check, the program says a
>   NullPointerException at the line where I assign the button's action
>   listener.

your use of `isFrameReady` ensures that you have created your `frame` successfully. inside your `main`, your posted request to event dispatch thread(EDT) using call `EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){})`: removing the check `isFrameReady`, you were going to call `frame.getButton()` in main thread but the  `frame` have not been yet created by `frame = new ProgressMonitorTest();`  in the EDT and thus a `NullPointerException` occurs.

> If I keep the above check, then clicking on the button does nothing.

you should understand by now, that above check is nothing to do with button click. The button is not doing anything because the GUI got freezed for violating swing's single threading rule. Put your incrementing `for` loop of the `actionPerformed` method inside another thread as the following code fragement shows and execute it from there. you will see that it works fine.

```
 new Thread(){
    public void run()
    {
       for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
           //whatever you were doing.
        }
    }
   }.start();
```

> Keeping the above check and then debugging this, I let it wait for
>   some time before it gets to the line where the action listener. In
>   this case, it works but immediately quits saying it can't call
>   invokeAndWait from the event handling thread.

`SwingUtitlies.invokeAndWait()` blocks the  current thread and waits until  the  EDT  is  done executing the task given to it. As `actionPerformed()` function is already running inside EDT, so calling `SwingUtitlies.invokeAndWait()` from the current thread:EDT would block the current thread:EDT which should not be allowed. Don't use `invokeAndWait` for this case. you should call `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` instead.

However I don't think you will get anything until you understand Swing threading model. Read the javadoc and some internet resource. DO HAVE The book Filthy Rich Clients and try the example the book offered: You will have a greater knowledge in graphical effects then any other resource can provide.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and the book suggestion.
One question - aren't the place from where im assigning the action listener(application thread), which is outside of EventQueue.invokeLater and the EDT different threads ? Or is that different ?

Comment: I will not answer your question directly. you will understand which thread you are in now by calling `system.out.println(Thread.currentThread())` function. Put this code inside various block of code and run. You will see by yourself and you will get the answer yourself

Comment: Thanks ! I'll do that !

Comment: I tried putting my actionPerformed logic in a new Thread() and it worked. Now I dont understand why calling it from a new thread works, and why calling it from the main application thread. I also couldnt find an answer for this anywhere. Can you explain that ?

Comment: i have already said that in my answer. when you are executing your task from the EDT in actionPerformed() function your GUI freezes. That is why we need execute the for loop inside another thread.